# Neo4j, Cypher: Fetching news feed (Graphiti)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to fetch news feed of a user?

Fetching news feed of user with id =`4084079`

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE ID(u)=4084079  
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(u)-[r:Ego*..]->(friend:User) 
WHERE all(r2 in relationships(p) 
    WHERE r2.user_id=4084079) 
WITH friend MATCH (friend)-[:FeedNext*]->(feed) 
RETURN labels(feed), feed, feed.timestamp 
ORDER BY toInt(feed.timestamp) DESC 
SKIP 1 
LIMIT 10
```

---

This line tries to match the longest path which turns into infinity, and hence the query hangs. `WHERE` AND `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause are getting executed separately.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(u)-[r:Ego*..]->(friend:User)
```

---

How to avoid `r` being matched for all `user_id`?

Writing query this way returns a syntax error.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(u)-[r:Ego{user_id:4084079}*..]->(friend:User)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(u)-[r:Ego*.. {user_id:4084079}]->(friend:User)
```

You can also leave off the ..

```
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(u)-[r:Ego* {user_id:4084079}]->(friend:User)
```

But I'd probably limit it to a max-path-length.

Also Cypher might not yet be the fastest solution here, that will change with the new query planner (try to prefix your query with `cypher 2.1.experimental` for a test).

Otherwise you might want to check out a server extension like this one:

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-activity-stream